# change one word of a textview on button click

Tags: android, onclick, textview

I have a very basic example that allows a user to select a item in a spinner and depending on the item selected it appears the correspondent image in a Image view.

Also I have a textview that says by default "Select an item" and when the item 1 is selected this textview shows "The name of item 1 is none" and when the item2 is selected it appears "The name of item 2 is none".

And now I have a editext and a button and I want to enter a name in the editext and when I enter a name in the editext (for example John) and click in the button I want that the text in the textview changes to "The name of item1 is john". Im trying with the code below but its not working. Do you know how to solve?

Example: If I write "john" and click in the button Instead of appearing "The name of item2 is john" appears "john The name of item2 is none".

activity xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.ricardorei.tpc.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="166dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="56dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="58dp"
        android:onClick="addName"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:entries="@array/spinner_values"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/button3"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="32dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="391dp"
        android:layout_height="51dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.369"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.48" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

string xml:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">tpc</string>
    <string-array name="spinner_values">
        <item>Select</item>
        <item>item1</item>
        <item>item2</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

code:

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        String string = String.valueOf(spinner.getSelectedItem());




        final ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);

        final TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);



        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        txt.setText("Select an item");
                        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.bg);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        txt.setText("The name of item1 is none");
                        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.item1);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        txt.setText("The name of item2 is none");
                        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.item2);
                        break;
                    default:
                        //Default image
                        //image.setImageResource(R.drawable.item2);
                        break;

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

    }

    public void addName(View view) {
        EditText editext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        txt.setText(txt.getText().replace(5, 1, editext.getText()) );

    }
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by **not working**? What does it do when you click the button?

Comment: If I write "john" and click in the button Instead of appearing "The name of item2 is john" appears "john The name of item2 is none".

Comment: You really just need to save off the name and position of the spinner, and do a String replace based of that

Comment: Why not do a replace(oldString, newString) instead of your index based replace. The problem above seems to your indexes.

Comment: Can you give a example? It just appears a replace function that uses indexes.

Comment: See answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better approach is to use tokens in your strings that will be replaced by the name the user chooses.
This way of doing it has the added benefit that even if the user changes the spinner selection, the name that the user chose will be replaced in the TextView.

First, add your strings to your strings.xml, with token placeholders:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">tpc</string>
    <string name="item_0">Select an item</string>
    <string name="item_1">The name of item1 is %1$s</string>
    <string name="item_2">The name of item2 is %1$s</string>
    <string-array name="spinner_values">
        <item>Select</item>
        <item>item1</item>
        <item>item2</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Then create member variables in order to keep track of the name and spinner position:

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String mName = "none";
    int mSpinnerPos = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //.........
    }
```

Modify your spinner code to update the current selected index, and also replace the name with the one the user has chosen:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                mSpinnerPos = 0;
                txt.setText(R.string.item_0);
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.bg);
                break;
            case 1:
                mSpinnerPos = 1;
                txt.setText(String.format(getString(R.string.item_1), mName));
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.item1);
                break;
            case 2:
                mSpinnerPos = 2;
                txt.setText(String.format(getString(R.string.item_2), mName));
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.item2);
                break;
            default:
                //Default image
                //image.setImageResource(R.drawable.item2);
                break;

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
});
```

And do the same for the button click event:

```
public void addName(View view) {
    EditText editext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    mName = editext.getText();

    TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    switch (mSpinnerPos) {
      case 0:
        //nothing to do
        break;
      case 1:
        txt.setText(String.format(getString(R.string.item_1), mName));
        break;
      case 2:
        txt.setText(String.format(getString(R.string.item_2), mName));
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but here "                txt.setText(String.format(getString(R.string.item_2), mName));
" it gives an error "Wrong argument count, format string item_2 requires 2 but format call supplies 1"

Comment: @JonD I did this without an IDE, let me double check that

Comment: Thanks, and theese (  String mName = "none";
  int mSpinnerPos = 0;) need a static right? Like: static String mName = "none";
 static int mSpinnerPos = 0;

Comment: No, not static, but class level instance variables.  Inside the class, and outside any methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below instead as a very simple fix (directly replacing "none" with the name):

```
txt.setText(txt.getText().toString().replace("none", editext.getText().toString()));
```

**Note**: You can only do this if the word "none" is present. This won't work if you want to replace a name with another name.

I'm surprised that you are able to get the `replace(int start, int end, CharSequence text)` method, as that is part of the `Editable` class. My Android Studio complains that it's not there.

Comment: Yes, that's why I left a "Note" above and also mentioned that my answer is a quick fix only.

Answer (score -1):

So, rather than splicing up a textview, it'd be better to make a separate textview, and just set the text for that one textview.  For example, here is another textview of id "name"

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="firstString"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/name"
    android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/editText2"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText2" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="nameString"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/button3" />
```

In your code, I have moved all of your view variables to the top of the class...  You can initialize them in onCreate and then you can reference them everywhere in your activity.  This means you only have to declare them once.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView result;
 ImageView image;
 TextView txt;
EditText editText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    String string = String.valueOf(spinner.getSelectedItem());

    result=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);




    image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
    txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);



    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    txt.setText("Select an item");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    txt.setText("The name of item1 is none");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    txt.setText("The name of item2 is none");
                    break;
                default:
                    //Default image
                    //image.setImageResource(R.drawable.item2);
                    break;

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

}

public void addName(View view) {
    result.setText(editText.getText());
}
```

}

Notice that in addName, I'm just setting that result textview with the text from the edit text without having to change that spinner result textview.

Hope this helps!

***EDIT***

Additionally, if you want to use the same text view, instead of replacing, you can always do textview.append("yourString").  That might be simpler.